# Spring Java Config | How to fetch IndexedArgumentsValue from BeanDefinition

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

Consider the following example :

### Config Class

@Configuration
public class MyTestConfig {

```
@Value("${const.arg.a}") String constArgA;
@Value("${const.arg.b}") String constArgB;

@Bean
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties(){
    SystemPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer = new SystemPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertyConfigurer.setLocation( "test.properties" );
    propertyConfigurer.setPropertyPrefixValue("TEST");
    propertyConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders( true );
    return propertyConfigurer;
}

@Bean
public SpringTest springTest(){
    return new SpringTest(constArgA, constArgB);

}
```

}

---

### Bean

public class SpringTest {

```
private String constArgA;
private String constArgB;

public SpringTest(String constArgA, String constArgB){
    this.constArgA = constArgA;
    this.constArgB = constArgB;

    System.out.println("constArgA " + constArgA);
    System.out.println("constArgB " + constArgB);
}

public void sayHello(){
    System.out.println("Hello, I hope this works");
    System.out.println("constArgA " + constArgA);
    System.out.println("constArgB " +  constArgB);
}
```

}

---

SystemPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is a extension of the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in which we try to manipulate some of the Bean Constructor arguments.

For my use case I need to access the constructor arguments but I see a empty list if I obtain a BeanDefinition from ConfigurableListableBeanFactory .

To be precise all of the following for the Bean 'SpringTest' are empty :

```
beanDefinition.getPropertyValues();
beanDefinition.getConstructorArgumentValues().getIndexedArgumentValues();
beanDefinition.getConstructorArgumentValues().getGenericArgumentValues();
```

I expect to receive constArgA and constArgB in the ConstructorArgumentValues.

Now if I replace Java Based Config with a Xml Based Config as follows :

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

<bean
    class="com.abc.SystemPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>test.properties</value>
    </property>
    <property name="propertyPrefixValue">
        <value>TEST</value>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="springTest" class="com.abc.SpringTest" >
    <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" value="${const.arg.a}" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" type="java.lang.String" value="${const.arg.b}" />        
</bean>
</beans>
```

Now if I try to access my BeanDefinition I get the 2 constructor arguments in :

beanDefinition.getConstructorArgumentValues().getIndexedArgumentValues()

Can you please help me to understand what is the difference in these 2 configuration ways and if I want to use a Java Based Config , how do I access the constructor arguments on my beans ? I basically need to inject my properties from a property file as constructor arguments and need to perform some processing on it through my implementation of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

Answer (score 0):

In @configuration class, I usually do it like this

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/test.properties")
public class MyTestConfig {

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public SpringTest springTest(){
        return new SpringTest(env.getRequiredProperty("const.arg.a"), env.getRequiredProperty("const.arg.b"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but what I am trying to understand is why doesnt the following return me anything for my Bean 'SpringTest' :

    BeanDefinition beanDefinition =   configurableListableBeanFactory.getBean(SpringTest.class);
    beanDefinition.getPropertyValues();     beanDefinition.getConstructorArgumentValues().getIndexedArgumentValues();
 beanDefinition.getConstructorArgumentValues().getGenericArgumentValues();

The constructor arguments on the bean return an empty list if I use Java Based Config, but returns 2 arguments if I use xml based config.